# useEffect will re-render everytime its dependencies change?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set admin object in store. Root component is re-render every time  components are change. So I use useEffect with empty dependency array []. But I got eslint warning missing dependencies admin and setAdmin. So I add this to the dependency array.

**My confusion is: **

At first, I think useEffect will re-render every time  components are change because I add admin and setAdmin as its dependencies and admin object is not the same each time because object is reference.

But, when I test it out, useEffect render once. I really confuse about this.

Can you explain me how i am misunderstanding?

Thanks

```
import Sidebar from "@/components/side-bar"
import { IAdmin, useAdminStore } from "@/store"
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { Outlet, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Root() {
  const { admin } = useLoaderData() as { admin: IAdmin }
  const { setAdmin } = useAdminStore()

  useEffect(() => setAdmin(admin), [admin, setAdmin])

  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen w-full gap-8">
      <Sidebar />
      <main className="flex-1 p-4">
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your "terminology" is a little bit wrong. `useEffect` doesn't re-render. It runs the effect, which is the function you pass into the `useEffect` hook. Components rerender, and if the dependencies are different from the last render, then the effect is run.

Second, if `setAdmin` is returned by something like `useState` or redux, or a decent state management library, it will be referentially stable. Meaning it will have the same reference in every render, so you can safely add it to the dependency list of `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`, etc.

Finally coming to your question. Your effect is not running multiple times because `admin` is simply the same object, since `useLoaderData` [returns a stable object](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data), ie it doesn't change between renders, unless the loader function is called again for some reason. And since you are setting the state to the same thing, react doesn't rerender the component and the effect doesn't run again.